# Rx Operators. Ignore until next is emitted

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, reactivex

In my app I have time consuming logic which can be started in many ways, let's say automatically or manually by user.

```java
// Let's describe different event sources as relays
val autoStarts = PublishRelay.create<Unit>()
val manualStarts = PublishRelay.create<Unit>()
val syncStarts = PublishRelay.create<Unit>()

// This is my time consuming operation.
fun longOperation() = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).take(1).map { Unit }

val startsDisposable = Observable
        .merge(
                autoStarts.flatMap { Observable.just(Unit).delay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) },
                manualStarts
        )
        .subscribe(syncStarts) // merge emissions of both sources into one

val syncDisposable = syncStarts
        .concatMap {
            longOperation()
        }
        .subscribe(autoStarts) // end of long operation trigger start of auto timer
```

Start relays could produce many emissions. Let's say user clicks button for manual start and there is 5 secons left until auto start by timer. Both events will lead to `longOperation()` to start if it was simple `flatMap`.
I want only one thread to run `longOperation()` inside, so if it's running now and not finished - ignore start emissions, anyway finish will lead to timer restart.

`ConcatMap` helps me there at half - it adds `longOperation()` to "queue" so they are processed one by one, but how could I write this to ignore any further starts until first one is completely finished?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `flatMap()` with an extra integer argument to limit parallelism.

```
syncStarts
  .onBackpressureDrop()               // 1
  .flatMap(() -> longOperation(), 1)  // 2
  ...
```

1. Drop any emissions that occur while `flatMap()` is busy.
2. The number 1 is the number of subscriptions that `flatMap()` makes, essentially forcing operations to be sequential.

The above does the functions that you want. However, you didn't specify what you wanted to happen once `longOperation()` is running: did you want another operation to start immediately after? If so, you need to change the back pressure handling to queue up at most one emission.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution, this second parameter of flatMap makes sense. onBackPressureDrop() means syncStarts should be Flowable if we talk about RxJava 2, right? What will happen if we remove line 1?

Comment: About another operation start - no, I just want to wait next timer tick, nothing more. But if I want - it'll behave like concatMap but with the number of starts equals to what backpressure handling says, right? You said "change the back pressure handling to queue up at most one emission", how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
val syncDisposable = syncStarts
    .concatMap {
        longOperation()
    }
    .take(1) // Complete after first longOperation() emit next item
    .repeat() // Resubscribe to this chain onCompleted so we continue to listen syncStarts ticks
    .subscribe(autoStarts)
```

While it works it doesn't look very clean. Bob's answer looks more logical though it requires chain to be `Flowable`.